# cURL not functioning correctly when PHP script run from Shell

Tags: php, batch-file, curl, cookies, cron

I have a cron.php file which fetches data from a webpage and saves it daily. This webpage requires authentication to access the data being retrieved, and therefore the cron.php file uses cURL to login and save the cookie, then using this cookie when requesting the final page.

The cron.php file is stored on a windows server and therefore I need to use the windows task scheduler to execute it daily. I have the windows scheduled task setup to call shellscript.vbs

**shellscript.vbs**

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Apache24\htdocs\Salesforce\script.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

**script.bat**

```
"C:\PHP\php.exe" -f "C:\Apache24\htdocs\Salesforce\cron.php"
```

The issue is that for some reason cURL is not able to access the target page when cron.php is run through this process. When I execute cron.php in my web browser it downloads the page and updates the local file just fine, it is only through executing the script.bat contents that it fails.

I'm thinking there is an issue with cURL not being able to use the cookie properly or not following the redirect, and this is the reason it is not retrieving the correct data but I have absolutely no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just installing `wget` for windows and used the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" -q -O NUL http://example.com/cron.php
```